# Logistic decay in mathematical biology

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology, logistic-regression

I am studying a course of Mathematical Biology.
I am trying to interp the following ODE:

$$
\frac{dR}{dt} = \beta R-\gamma(1+\frac{R}{K})R
$$

My attempt:

$R$ describes a population in time $t$

$\beta R $ is a growth term

$
-\gamma(1+\frac{R}{K})R
$ is  a decay term. there is no limiting term like logistic growth $
\gamma(1-\frac{R}{K})R
$, so what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is just a form of the logistic equation written slightly differently from normal:
\begin{align}
\frac{dR}{dt}&=(\beta-\gamma)R\Big(1-\frac{\gamma R}{K(\beta-\gamma)}\Big)\\
&=rR\Big(1-\frac{R}{K'}\Big)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ r=\beta-\gamma\ $ is the growth rate, and $\ K'=\big(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}-1\big)K\ $ is the carrying capacity.  Without any details of how the model was constructed I don't think it's possible to know what physical quantities the parameters $\ \beta$, $\ \gamma\ $, or $\ K\ $ represent.